# Compress video with ffmpeg programatically - i.e. using C libraries instead of command line or wrapper

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to find some examples or guidelines that help show how to compress a video programatically using ffmpeg API's (i.e. the C API's not the command line).

In other words I would like to achieve the equivalent of the following ffmpeg command line:

ffmpeg -i inoutVideo.mp4 -strict experimental -acodec aac CompressedVideo_aac.mp4

but using the appropriate API calls from a C program.

I can already do this by creating a wrapper around the 'ffmpeg.c' program but I am trying to understand how to achieve this with the C libraries directly.

I realise I can simply(!) read the source code of ffmpeg.c to see what it does, but I was hoping for something that either provides and overview or a specific example for video compression.

Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the example programs in the `doc/examples` directory of the ffmpeg source tree?

Comment: @njahnke, Yes I did take a look but there is no compression example and the text 'compress' occurs only once in all files in the directory and this is in an example about muxing syntethic streams. I was hoping for a high level principles document preferably, or failing that an actual compression example so I could look at it and try to reverse engineer the high level approach.

Comment: You probably want the term "encoding". Check `decoding_encoding.c`.

Comment: @43  https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/videokit/uk_co_halfninja_videokit_Videokit.c  seems like a place to branch out from in finding other entry pts within the "main" module or within the shared lib.

Comment: @njahnke - Thanks for the links. I am familiar with the theory of decoding and encoding to different codecs etc. I was hoping for something which explained at a high level how ffmpeg approaches compression specifically, not just to see how the actual compression decisions were made (i.e. choosing codec etc) but also to understand the underlying ffmpeg philosophy and architecture, the idea being that this will make it easier to wade through the source code for other use cases also.